# copying and replacing folders in xcode4 code

Tags: xcode4, cordova, cvs

So, I am working on this phonegap-based app. Most of our code is checked in cvs but since I cannot get that to work in my Mac or Xcode4 for that matter, I have to switch to making it work with flash drive. 
The problem happens with the wwww folder. The old one works fine but when I replace it with the current updated www folder, it builds fine but it just stops running. Also, all the files are shown in black (not red) and I am pretty sure xcode4 is able to see all my files. 
Please help me. I have waisted about 4 days trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobileOverload your suggestions are good but those didn't help me as I was already doing them. Although I will take your suggestions for good source control. 
Anyways, what fixed mine was using phonegap-1.3.0.js. The updated code had phone gap-1.4.0 and when even after changing the index.html to look for that and installing that phone gap, it didn't work quite well. 
Earlier, I had the same problem phonegap-1.0.0 didn't work either. I don't know why this is. May xcode4 only like phone gap-1.3.0.js but it seems to me a phonegap bug. I would like to have other people's thoughts on this and if they have encountered a same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap projects require that when you add the www folder to the project you use the option to create folder references. This way the www folder will get copied in at compile time. \

[image: Folder linking]

Another thing to note is that if you change the contents of the www folder outside xcode you will need to clean your project before seeing any changes on the device.

We have a couple phonegap projects that we use with source control. I have come to find that even though we use svn Xcode is still not very good at managing the source control interactions and therefore we use Cornerstone 2 for all source control operations. Try finding a good source control app that handles CVS and use it separately from Xcode. Check out a working copy of the www folder onto your computer and then link it to the Xcode Proj.